# SPWeb object will be dispose everytime or not?

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-application, application-pages, object-model

I have following code in my web part. I want to know whether this property _web will create object each time whenever I use it. If yes then will it be disposed every time.

```
private SPWeb _web
{
    get
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(<SiteURL>))
        {
            return site.OpenWeb();
        }
    }
}
```

Will appreciate immediate response.

**Update:**
@Evariste: We are using this code in SharePoint 2013 application page deployed as site collection feature.

Getting below stack trace of error in ULS.

> Unexpected 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 Stack trace:    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListCollection.GetListByName(String strListName, Boolean bThrowException)     at
>   AgreementApprovalRequest.Layouts.AgreementApprovalRequest.CreateNewAggApprRequest.GetDetailFromUI()
>   at
>   AgreementApprovalRequest.Layouts.AgreementApprovalRequest.CreateNewAggApprRequest.saveFormDetails()
>   at
>   AgreementApprovalRequest.Layouts.AgreementApprovalRequest.CreateNewAggApprRequest.BtnSubmit_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)     at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception
>   error)     at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb)     at
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr
>   pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)     at
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr
>   rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData,
>   Int32 flags)  78635e9d-13dc-e0ea-fac5-34124891f447

**Code:**
Getting Error in two different places. Shown below

```
SPList docLibrary = _web.Lists[ListName.LegalAgreementTemplate.ToString()];  
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_web.Url))
```

Regards,
Nafe

Comment: 1. Although it depends on what you are going to do with an object, you should consider the objects as identical. However, using a singleton pattern might be a bit more reliable. 2. It will not be disposed unless you do it explicitly.

Comment: can you please paste that piece of code where this error is occurring?

Comment: Please note you are using '_web' at both the places. are you getting the error at any other SPWeb object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong for two main reasons:

1. You're returning an `SPWeb` object belonging to a closed `SPSite`. That's not good because closing the `SPSite` may actually close all child `SPWeb` under the hood. Meaning the caller may be using a closed `SPWeb`.
2. Having a property like that lets callers assume they can call it as often as they want, e.g. like this: `if(_web....){_web...}` witch is not a good practice here since `_web` has actually a huge cost. And it' always returning a *different* `SPWeb` object, so for instance such code `_web.Title = "New Title"; _web.Update()` won't have any effect.

If you tell us in which context your code is used (Web context like in a Web part, SharePoint exe context like for a timer job, or unknown like a workflow) we can try to find a better design. But something like the following should always do the trick:

```
class SPWrapper : IDisposable
{
   string m_siteUrl;
   public SPWrapper(string siteUrl)
   {
      m_siteUrl = siteUrl;
   }

   SPSite m_site = null;
   SPSite Site
   {
      get
      {
         if(m_site == null)
            m_site = new SPSite(m_siteUrl);
         return m_site;
      }
   }

   SPWeb m_web = null;
   SPWeb Web
   {
      get
      {
         if(m_web == null)
            m_web = Site.OpenWeb();
         return m_web;
      }
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
      if(m_web != null)
         m_web.Dispose();
      if(m_site != null)
         m_site.Dispose();
   }
}
```

It's up to the caller to actually call `.Dispose` on `SPWrapper` when it's done with all operations on `Web` and `Site`.
Another version would be to use a singleton on `SPWrapper` but that's only if you're *not* in a Web context (in Web context don't cache/store_in_static variables any SP object).
In a Web context, you could use another trick, like associating one `SPWrapper` to the page, and disposing it from the `UnLoad` (or `OnError`) event of the page.

**Update**
OK, after reviewing additional info you provided:

1. The error you see can probably be explained by the `SPWeb` being closed implicitely by the parent `SPSite` (itself closed explicitely in your property). What's the error message?
2. As you're in an application page (_layouts, i.e. Web context), her's a piece of code more suited for your needs (implementing the idea of opening the Web once, and closing it at unload time). However, please, one question: why don't you use the contextual `SPWeb` (`SPContext.Current.Web`) here?

The code for an application page. The idea with it is to make you layout pages inherit from `MyLayoutsPageBase` instead of `LayoutsPageBase`:

```
public class MyLayoutsPageBase : LayoutsPageBase
{
   protected virtual string UrlOfSiteToOpen
   {
      get
      {
         // TODO
         return <site_url>; 
      }
   }

   SPSite m_site = null;
   protected SPSite Site
   {
      get
      {
         if(m_site == null)
            m_site = new SPSite(UrlOfSiteToOpen);
         return m_site;
      }
   }

   SPWeb m_web = null;
   protected SPWeb Web
   {
      get
      {
         if(m_web == null)
            m_web = Site.OpenWeb();
         return m_web;
      }
   }

   protected override void OnError(EventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnError(e);
      CleanUpSPObjects();
   }

   protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
   {
      base.OnUnload(e);
      CleanUpSPObjects();
   }

   private void CleanUpSPObjects() // We close any SPSite/SPWeb we open explicitely
   {
       if(m_web != null)
         m_web.Dispose();
      if(m_site != null)
         m_site.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: Updated question with error and context. It is application page.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion. This code is not written by me. It was working earlier, under support I am handling it. will discuss developer team for changes.

Comment: Looking at the code you provided + the "random" aspect of the error, I'm quite sure the problem is about an `SPWeb` being used while disposed. The error is random and happens most of the time under load, when a lot of users are browsing the site, isn't it? This is because the underlying `SPRequest` object is really disposed "later", "later" being "very soon" under load.

Comment: It sounds good. I will discuss with the team.

Answer (score 2):

No. The instance of your Web you create with .OpenWeb() will not be disposed, only your site will be disposed. You need to call .Dispose() on your web when you don't need it anyomore or put using around it.

Comment: Also added stack trace of error

Comment: why are you opening a new site instead of using _web.Site?

Comment: I am creating site object under Elevated Privileges so that I can assign permission to user on document.

Comment: Don't you need to get your list from the elevated web?